# What does 介绍人 mean?

Tags: meaning

I have the following text:

```
丁力波的爸爸是加拿大人，妈妈是中国人。汉语是他爸爸，妈妈的 “介绍人”。
```

What does **“介绍人”** mean?

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

介绍人 literally mean "introducer/ someone who introduces"

汉语 (Chinese language) is the introducer that introduced 他爸爸 (his father) and 他妈妈 (his mother) to each other

Of course 汉语 is not a person and cannot actually introduce two people to each other, it is a metaphor for 'thing that brings two people together'

Example of a sentence using the literal meaning of 介绍人:

> 沒有會員作為介绍人不可以入會
>
> Cannot join the club without a club member as your introducer

Someone who introduces you to the other club members is your introducer (介绍人) ; someone who vouches for you is your voucher (保證人)

Comment: Not to confuse 介绍人 with 媒人婆, (Méirén pó) The latter specifically means "matchmaker", though the former could also be loosely considered a matchmaker but not specifically.

Comment: I prefer the  gender-neutral  term 媒人" (matchmaker)

Comment: LOL, I've yet to come across a 媒人公 :) For some inexplicable reason, matchmakers in Chinese socio-cultural history were, (I would stick my neck out and say), exclusively females, more particularly middle-age females. Maybe I see too many period Hong Kong movies. But I suppose it was more socially acceptable for a female to approach the family of the potential bride than a male would be.

Comment: Have you heard of 月老 or 月下老人? It is the term for male matchmaker

Comment: No, I have not. I learn something new today. Thanks.